# CSS Display None not working on image tag

Tags: css

I am trying to hide an image following this tutorial [Here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ZYV6dYtz4HA&list=PL0eyrZgxdwhwNC5ppZo_dYGVjerQY3xYU&index=18). But my image still shows even I used

> display : none ;

**Here is my Html code :**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
    <img class="img-ban" src="img/banner.jpg" alt="banner">
    <div class="wrapper">
        <article class="imh-info">
            <h1>Yooo</h1>
            <p>Kasd sed justo no invidunt et duo ea ipsum nonumy, sed ea no aliquyam nonumy et, consetetur sed et lorem erat accusam, takimata dolor ipsum rebum sadipscing eirmod labore. Est consetetur justo duo ipsum erat dolore,</p><p> et justo dolore elitr dolores et dolor. Diam sit lorem takimata dolor ut at voluptua, et lorem et eos lorem. Stet diam ipsum dolores elitr accusam eirmod. Ut et accusam ipsum rebum voluptua magna est. Justo eirmod dolor no duo magna consetetur accusam labore,.</p>
        </article>
        <img class="img-worker" src="img/work.jpg" alt="worker">
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

**Here is my style.css:**

```
    *{
        margin:0;
        padding: 0;

     }    

     .wrapper
     {
         width: 100%;
     }

     .img-ban{        
         display: none;    
      }

     .img-info
     {
         width:100%;    
     }

     .img-info h2
     {
         padding:30px 30px 20px;
         font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
         font-size: 50px;
         color:#111;
         line-height: 44px;        
     }

     .img-info p
     {
         padding:0px 30px 20px;
         font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
         font-size: 60px;
         color:#111;
         line-height: 24px;      
     }

     .img-worker
     {
         width:100%;
     }

    @media only screen and (min-width:768px)
    {
        .img-ban{
            display: block;
            width:100%;
            padding-bottom: 30px;
        }

        .wrapper
        {
            width: 600px;
            margin: 0 auto ;
        }

        .img-info h2
        {
            padding:20px 0px 0px;
            font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
        }

        .img-info p
        {
             padding:20px 0px 0px;
        }

        .img-worker{
            background-size:contain;
            height: 100%;
            padding-top: 50px;
        }
    }

    @media only screen and (min-width:1000px)
    {

    }
```

I tried using CTRL+F5  to refresh the page and clearing the chrome cache but the problem still persists.If someone can guide me where the problem exacly come from I will appreciate it very much.

Comment: You haven't added `style.css` to the page.

Comment: As Ibu says — in the `<head>` you need to import the stylesheet, something like `<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">`

Comment: in your style.css, img-ban is set to display:none; but your html uses class img-worker. You have to set img-worker to display:none (or visibility:hidden; ) if this is the image that you want to hide.

Comment: @Ibu it's true I didn't pay attention I just forgot to add the css link . For a moment I thought that there was a problem that I coudnt figure out . Thank you Sir and Thank you all for helping a starter like me to learn .